# Getting 404 error if requesting a page through proxy, but 200 if connecting directly

Tags: http, proxy, http-status-code-404, varnish

I am developing an HTTP proxy in Java. I resend all the data from client to server without touching it, but for some URLs (for example [this](http://msc.wcdn.co.il/w/w-200/1902047-41.jpg)) server returns the 404 error if I am connecting through my proxy.

The requested URL uses Varnish caching, so it might be the root of problem. I cannot reconfigure it - it is not my.

If I request that URL directly with browser, the server returns 200 and the image is shown correctly.

I am stuck because I even do not know what to read and how to compose a search request.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the `Host:` header of the re-issued request. The request going out from the proxy either has no Host header or it is broken (or only X-Host exists). Also take note that the proxy application will execute its own DNS lookup and that might yield a different IP address than your local computer (where you issued the original request).

This works:

```
> curl -s -D - -o /dev/null http://212.25.95.152/w/w-200/1902047-41.jpg -H "Host: msc.wcdn.co.il"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Cache-Control: max-age = 315360000
magicmarker: 1
Content-Length: 27922
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sun, 05 Jul 2015 00:52:08 GMT
X-Varnish: 2508753650 2474246958
Age: 67952
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache: HIT
```